# Spark reading from Azure Eventhub => StreamingQueryException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to collect Azure Eventhub messages using Spark/Python.
Every time, I get the exception "StreamingQueryException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit"

Any ideas please?

```
conf = {}
conf["eventhubs.connectionString"] = "Endpoint=sb://XXXXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXX=;EntityPath=XXXXXX"
                                      
read_df  = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**conf).load()
stream = read_df.writeStream.format("console").start()
stream.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Could you provide more information for others to replicate your issue? Please share how you construct your SparkConf, your sbt (or whichever build tool you are using) file, etc. would help contributors. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more details on how to craft a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I'm using versions Spark 3.0.1 / com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17

The session init is
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("teststream")
spark=spark.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.17")
spark=spark.getOrCreate()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for Version 2.3.15 and above, you need to encrypt the connection string in the configuration dictionary:

```
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#event-hubs-configuration